# Multiprocess Python Decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7

Sorry for any typos or bugs, I'm on my phone.

Basically I have a function in one module

```
#foo.py 
def foo(x):
    return x*x
```

That I want to decorate with a function that will submit this function to a ProcessPool (in my case, a ProcessPoolExecutor)

```
# process.py
_Pool = ProcessPoolExecutor() 

def proc_wrap(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) :
        return _Pool.submit(func, *args, **kwargs) 

    return wrapper
```

So I'm having 2 issues:

- the process pool gets re initialized every single time a new process is started, is there a way to wrap a process pool so that it looks global but doesn't get recreated every time?
- the function isn't picklable because it tried to do a lookup on `__builtins__`, even though `func.__module__`and `func.__name__` are correct, and importing the function into process.py doesn't work because the ids are different

Platform is Windows 10. I can post more detailed code if needed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to use `if __name__ == "__main__":` on Windows.  Since Windows lacks fork() (and more generally everything that makes programming nice), Python's `multiprocessing` module has to start a new process from scratch.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Right, and that would work if this module were being run directly, but I want to import this decorator to apply to functions in other modules, so my pool will be redefined for every single child process. Is the `if __name__ == "__main__" ` guard the only solution?